One Interface but different types?
I have single interface one is mostly all kind of types, but i want to use the same interface, again but with all types as "strings". how to do it without writing the types twice?
Thanks
interface #1
interface formValuesState {
  ownerType: string, 
  platformUrl?: string,
  serviceUrl?: string,
  fullName: string,
  email: string,
  password1: string,
  password2: string,
  agreeTermsCheckbox: string,
}

interface #2
interface formValuesState {
  ownerType: boolean, 
  platformUrl?: string,
  serviceUrl?: string,
  fullName: string,
  email: string,
  password1: string,
  password2: string,
  agreeTermsCheckbox: boolean,
}

how do i use the same one without writing it twice?
objects as example:
const data = {
  ownerType: true, 
  platformUrl?: 'test',
  serviceUrl?: 'test',
  fullName: 'test',
  email: 'test',
  password1: 'test',
  password2: 'test',
  agreeTermsCheckbox: false,
}

// data 2:
const data = {
  ownerType: 'test now as string', 
  platformUrl?: 'test',
  serviceUrl?: 'test',
  fullName: 'test',
  email: 'test',
  password1: 'test',
  password2: 'test',
  agreeTermsCheckbox: 'now as string',
}

Thanks for the help!

The best way I could think of is to use omit
  interface formErrorsState extends Omit<formValuesState, 'ownerType' | 'agreeTermsCheckbox'> {
    ownerType: string,
    agreeTermsCheckbox: string
  }

but I am not a big fan, it's a bit odd, maybe there's a better more "typescript" approach.

Given one type:
interface FormValuesState {
  ownerType: boolean, 
  platformUrl?: string,
  serviceUrl?: string,
  fullName: string,
  email: string,
  password1: string,
  password2: string,
  agreeTermsCheckbox: boolean,
}

you can use a mapped type to derive the other:
type FormValuesStateAsString = {[K in keyof FormValuesState]: string}

alternatively, you could use the utility type Record:
type FormValuesStateAsString = Record<keyof FormValuesState, string>;

The two solutions differ in how they handle optional properties: The mapped type keeps the optional keys optional, while the Record makes them mandatory.
If you need this in many places, you can use a generic type to reuse the derivation rule:
type StringValues<T extends object> = {[K in keyof T]: string};

const state: StringValues<FormValuesState> = ...
const otherState: StringValues<OtherFormValuesState> = ...


In this scenario one can use Unions defined by the pipe character |.
You can read it like X or Y. e.g: string | boolean reads string or boolean
interface formValuesState {
  ownerType: string | boolean, 
  platformUrl?: string,
  serviceUrl?: string,
  fullName: string,
  email: string,
  password1: string,
  password2: string,
  agreeTermsCheckbox: string | boolean,
}

Then use it
const data: formValuesState = {
  ownerType: "string", // OK
...
}
const data2: formValuesState = {
  ownerType: true, // OK
...
}


you can use MappedType to create the string version of the interface:
interface formValuesState {
  ownerType: boolean,
  platformUrl?: string,
  serviceUrl?: string,
  fullName: string,
  email: string,
  password1: string,
  password2: string,
  agreeTermsCheckbox: boolean,
}

type Stringify<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string;
};

type formValuesStateAsString = Stringify<formValuesState>;

const data1: formValuesState = {
  ownerType: true,
  platformUrl: 'test',
  serviceUrl: 'test',
  fullName: 'test',
  email: 'test',
  password1: 'test',
  password2: 'test',
  agreeTermsCheckbox: false,
};

const data2: formValuesStateAsString = {
  ownerType: 'test now as string',
  platformUrl: 'test',
  serviceUrl: 'test',
  fullName: 'test',
  email: 'test',
  password1: 'test',
  password2: 'test',
  agreeTermsCheckbox: 'now as string',
};

